# One point tracking - Image in Render Layers is not showing on the movie

Tags: rendering, tracking

[image]

Hi all, I am following a one point tracking tutorial on youtube and everything worked fine until the compositing stage. I am having trouble showing the Renter layers on the movie. Is there anything i missed? Please help!

Best Regards,
Gary

Answer (score 0):

you need to toogle the two inputs of the alpha over node